# Remove duplicate x-values from array of tuples

Tags: javascript, typescript, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6

I want to remove items from a javascript array iff the x-value of the tuple is duplicated in the array, in which case I want to take the max y-value and trash the others.

Ex:

```
arr = [[0,1],[0,2],[1,1],[1,1],[2,2],[2,2],[2,4]]
filtered = [[0,2],[1,1],[2,4]]
```

Please help me understand if `Array.prototype.filter`, or `Array.prototype.map` etc. can fix my problem. I am trying to utilize ES6 methods rather than just simply iterating through the list in mention.

Comment: Shout out to everyone who answered promptly and accurately. Y'all are the best.

Comment: is the data sorted? do you need the original inner arrays?

Comment: The data I was dealing with was not sorted and is not expected to be. I sort afterward with `data.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.reduce()` and `Array.map()`

```js
var data = [[0,1],[0,2],[1,1],[1,1],[2,2],[2,2],[2,4]];
var map = data.reduce((a, arr) => a.set(arr[0], Math.max((a.get(arr[0]) || arr[1]), arr[1])), new Map());

var result = Array.from(map);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @JacobMichaelis Happy to help you friend, Your welcome :-)

Comment: Hi, your code works perfectly :D I wanted to use it within Google Apps Script (GAS) to find duplicate x-values and to average the y-values, but sadly GAS doesn't support ES6 (yet). I tried rewriting the arrow function, but then I get "a.get is not a function" as an error. Do you know an ES5-compliant alternative?

Comment: @Kelvin Map() is also introduced in Es6 so you need to update that too. you can simply use a normal js object instead of map :-)

Comment: @amrendersingh Thanks, I've managed to _somehow_ rewrite it. May be not very efficient, but it works for now :)

Answer (score 2):

Is this this sort of thing your after?

```js
var arr = [[0,1],[0,2],[1,1],[1,1],[2,2],[2,2],[2,4],[5,6]]
// var filtered = [[0,2],[1,1],[2,4]]

// temp array to store key value pairs
var items = []
arr.map((item) => {
  let [x, y] = item
  // store the max value of y for this x in items
  if (typeof items[x] === 'undefined'){
    items[x] = y
  }else{
    items[x] = Math.max(items[x], y)
  }
})

var filtered = items.map((y, x) => {
  // rejoin data into x,y pairs
  return [x,y]
}).filter(a => !!a) // fitler undefined pairs

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you don't want to use filter. Filter is more for applying a boolean test to include or exclude elements. If you really wanted to use filter you could do something like

```
var newArr = arr.filter(function (elem)
    {
        allOtherX's = arr.filter(function(secondElem){return elem[0] == secondElem[0]});
        return elem[1] >= Math.max(...arr);
     });
```

However this is an ineffective way of doing this since you will be repeating alot of calulcations. I would recommend instead dividing the list into a bunch of lists based off of x-values.Such as

```
var buckets = {};
arr.map(function(elem) 
        {
           if(typeof(buckets[elem[0]]) == 'undefined')
                 buckets[elem[0]] = [];
           buckets[elem[0]].push(elem[1]);
           return elem; // Unneccessary
         });
var newArr = Object.keys(buckets).map(function (x)
         {
            return [x,Math.max(...buckets[x])];
         });
```

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner alternative: you can use `reduce` to aggregate the intermediary hash where key is `x` and value is `y`, and then convert it to the desired filtered array:

```
const arr = [[0,1],[0,2],[1,1],[1,1],[2,2],[2,2],[2,4]];

const dataObj = arr.reduce((all, [x,y]) => {

    all[x] = Math.max(y, all[x] || 0);

    return all;

}, {});

const filtered = Object.keys(dataObj).map(x => [Number(x), dataObj[x]]);

console.log(filtered);
```